# The length of the repeated sequence of a rational number

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

I saw somewhere that given p a co-prime to 10, the length of the repeated sequence of $\frac1p$ will be longer than $\log_{10} p$, and I can't find an explanation why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repeating sequence has $n$ digits then $p$ has to divide $10^n-1$

so $p$ cannot be bigger than $10^n-1$

so $p$ must be less than $10^n$

so $\log_{10}p$ must be less than $n$

Comment: Thanks! could you explain why in the first line $p$ has to divide $10^n -1$?

Comment: @Algosub because if $X$ is the repeating number, then $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{X}{10^n-1}$.  This shows that $p$ divides $10^n - 1$.

Comment: @Algosub: If you calculate $10^n \times \frac1p - \frac1p$ then it will have no repeating digits because the subtraction will eliminate matching digits in the tails: try $100\times \frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{11} = 9.090909\ldots - 0.090909\ldots=9$ as an example.  So  $\dfrac{10^n -1}{p}$ has no repeating digits.  And if $p$ is coprime to $10$ then it must then divide  $10^n-1$

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, Thanks!